# Setting up a scrabble game in R

Tags: r

I want to set up the "sack" full of letters of the game and give out random letters and remove them afterwards. I have several questions:
Question Nr.1
Right now I made a endlessly long list that contains every single letter that is in the sack, there must be an easier way to do this over a loop function.

```
 a<-c("Joker","Joker", "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B",..."W","W","X","Y","Y","Z")
```

Question Nr.2
with the function Sample (a,7) I can print out 7 random letters from the list. So now all I need to do is to subtract these letters from the list a, but everything I´ve looked up seems to remove all the letters (so If I pull out one "A", it removes all "A"s from the first list).

Bonus Question (does not need to be answered):
Setting up the board (it should be a nice printable graph) would probably be done over a Matrix. Where empty spaces could be marked with an O, Double points DP, Double word value DW and so on. I already know that this is well beyond my understanding, but would there be a way of automatically count how much a person gets for putting down a word at a certain place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(3222955)
# set up game
avail_pieces <- c("Joker", LETTERS[1:3])
count_pieces <- c(2, 7, 3, 4)
sack <- rep(avail_pieces, count_pieces)
sack
#[1] "Joker" "Joker" "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "B"     "B"     "B"     "C"    
#[14] "C"     "C"     "C"

# start game
ind1 <- sample(seq_len(length(sack)), 5, replace=FALSE)
hand1 <- sack[ind1]
# update sack
sack <- sack[-ind1]
hand1
#[1] "A"     "C"     "B"     "Joker" "A"    
sack
#[1] "Joker" "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "A"     "B"     "B"     "C"     "C"     "C" 

# repeat for hand2, ...
```

Board representation as a matrix is perfectly sane, though you might want to ask another question, specifying the exact rule for counting points.

Comment: I´ve updated it with my information and it works perfectly. One question: the replace=FALSE in the sample function, means that after each number that has been created, the others have a higher probability to come?

Comment: `?sample` will help: `replace=F` stands for sampling without replacement, i.e. `sample(sack, 3, replace=F)` may not contain 3 Jokers, whereas `sample(sack, 3, replace=T)` may.

Answer (score 11):

I read your question and was interested to see if I could do something similar. Here's my implementation (which is a bit messy and could be made more efficient). I didn't implement everything (i.e. only the word multiple scores, not the letter multiples) and it only counts the word in line (i.e. doesn't score the side rows).

It also has functions for partial words, and a dictionary.

Hopefully it will give you some ideas - here's an animation:

[image]

```
##############################
# PREREQUISITES              #
##############################

require(ggplot2)     # for the plot
require(gridExtra)   # to arrange the board and panels
require(data.table)  # for fast dictionary lookup
require(dplyr)       # for data manipulation
require(grid)        # for gpar

##############################
# UTILITY FUNCTIONS          #
##############################

tb <- theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            legend.position="none",
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            panel.border=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            plot.background=element_blank())

strip.word<-function(subword,word,returnExact=F){
  temp.word<<-word
  lapply(1:nchar(subword),function(x)temp.word<<-sub(substr(subword,x,x),"",temp.word))
  ifelse(returnExact,nchar(temp.word)==(nchar(word)-nchar(subword)),return(temp.word))
}

char.vec<-function(s){
  unlist(lapply(1:nchar(s),function(x)substr(s,x,x)))
}

##############################
# LOAD SCRABBLE DICTIONARY   #
# AND INDEX                  #
##############################
# NB remove hashes to run once!
#scrabble.dictionary<-data.table(read.table(file="https://raw.github.com/jmlewis/valett/master/scrabble/sowpods.txt",header=F,col.names="words"))
#setkey(scrabble.dictionary,words)

##############################
# LOAD RULES                 #
# LETTERS (DIST & SCORES)    #
##############################

rules<-read.csv(text="letter,score,num
A,1,8
B,3,2
C,3,2
D,2,4
E,1,12
F,4,2
G,2,3
H,4,2
I,1,9
J,8,1
K,5,1
L,1,4
M,3,2
N,1,6
O,1,8
P,3,2
Q,10,1
R,1,6
S,1,4
T,1,6
U,1,4
V,4,2
W,4,2
X,8,1
Y,4,2
Z,10,1
0,0,2",header=T)

# INDEX RULES BY LETTER
rownames(rules)<-rules$letter

##############################
# MAKE EMPTY BOARD           #
##############################

board<-expand.grid(c=LETTERS[1:15],r=15:1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
triple.word<-data.frame(c=c("A","H","O","A","O","A","H","O"),r=c(1,1,1,8,8,15,15,15),stringsAsFactors=F,t.w=3)
double.word<-data.frame(c=c("B","C","D","E","K","L","M","N","B","C","D","E","K","L","M","N","H"),r=c(2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,14,13,12,11,11,12,13,14,8),stringsAsFactors=F,d.w=2)
board.filled<-merge(merge(board,triple.word,all.x=T),double.word,all.x=T)
board.filled[is.na(board.filled)]<-1
valids<-unique(c(board$r,as.character(board$c))) # used for checking bounds of words within board

##############################
# INITIALISE                 #
# BOARD, SACK & TRAYS        #
##############################

init.game<-function(seed=1){words<<-data.frame(r=c(),c=c(),lab=c(),stringsAsFactors=F)
                      tray<<-data.frame(player=c(rep(1,7),rep(2,7)),tiles=c(NA),stringsAsFactors=F)
                      # FILL THE SACK
                      sack<<-data.frame(letter=unlist(apply(rules,1,function(x)rep(x[1],x[3]))))
                      # SHUFFLE THE SACK
                      set.seed(seed)  #>>>>>>>>>>>> REMOVE THIS FOR A REAL GAME
                      sack$letter<<-sample(sack$letter,nrow(sack))
                      scorecard<<-data.frame(player=c(),word=c(),score=c())
                            player<<-1                                       # START PLAYER 1
}


switch.player<-function()player<<-ifelse(player==1,2,1)  # SWWITCH FUNCTION


##############################
# FUNCTION TO                #
# PLOT BOARD (WITH WORDS)    #
# AND TO FILL EACH TRAY      #
##############################

fill.board<-function(){
   g<-ggplot(board.filled) + 
    geom_tile(aes(c,r,fill=factor(t.w*d.w)),color="red") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd", name="SQUARE\n", labels=c("","2x WORD","3x WORD")) +
    theme_bw() + coord_fixed(ratio=1,xlim=c(0.5:15.5),ylim=c(0.5:15.5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1:15)) +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
    ifelse(nrow(words)==0,
           return(g),
           return(g + geom_point(aes(x=c,y=as.integer(r)),color="black",data=words,size=14,shape=22,fill="yellow",alpha=0.7) + 
                    geom_text(aes(x=c,y=as.integer(r),label=gsub("0"," ",lab)),data=words,size=9)  
           ))
}

fill.tray<-function(letters,p=1){
  n<-length(letters)
  g<-qplot(1:7,1)+geom_tile(color="white",size=1,fill="lightblue") +
  theme_bw() + coord_fixed(ratio=1,xlim=c(0.25:10),ylim=c(0.25,1.75)) + tb +
  geom_point(aes(8,1),alpha=0.8,fill=ifelse(p==player,"red","grey"),size=13,shape=22) +
  geom_text(aes(8,1,label=paste0("P",p)),size=5,color="white") +
    geom_text(aes(9,1,label=sum(scorecard[scorecard$player==p,"score"])),size=5,color="blue")    
  ifelse(n==0,
         return(g),
         return(g+geom_point(aes(x=1:n,y=rep(1,n)),size=14,shape=22,fill="yellow",alpha=0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1:n,y=rep(1,n),label=gsub("0"," ",letters)),size=9)) 
  )
}

##############################
# FUNCTION TO                #
# DRAW THE BOARD             #
# AND TRAYS FOR EACH PLAYER  #
##############################

draw.game<-function(){

  ifelse(nrow(scorecard)==0,grb<-rectGrob(),grb<-tableGrob(scorecard %.% arrange(player),gp=gpar(cex=0.6)))

  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(fill.tray(tray[tray$player==1 & !is.na(tray$tiles),2],1),
                                     fill.board(),
                                     fill.tray(tray[tray$player==2 & !is.na(tray$tiles),2],2),
                                     ncol=1,heights=c(0.15,0.7,0.15)),grb,ncol=2,widths=c(0.8,0.2))
}

draw.tiles<-function(n=7){
  n.t<-min(n,nrow(sack))
  draw<-sack[0:n.t,1]
  sack<<-data.frame(letter=sack[-(0:n.t),])
  c(as.character(draw),rep(NA,(n-n.t)))
}

##############################
# FUNCTION TO                #
# ADD EACH WORD              #
# TO THE BOARD               #
##############################

add.word<-function(word,c="H",r=8,d=1){
  word<-gsub(" ","0",word)
  c.ix<-match(c,LETTERS)
  word.len<-nchar(word)
  word.start<-c(c,r)
  word.col<-match(word.start[1],LETTERS)
  ifelse(d==1,
         word.grid<-data.frame(LETTERS[word.col:(word.col+word.len-1)],word.start[2],c(strsplit(word,"")),stringsAsFactors=F),
         word.grid<-data.frame(word.start[1],as.numeric(word.start[2]):(as.numeric(word.start[2])-word.len+1),c(strsplit(word,"")),stringsAsFactors=F))
  colnames(word.grid)<-c("c","r","lab")

  # work out which letters are already on the board, and which are needed
  existing.letters<-merge(word.grid,words)[,"lab"]
  tray.letters<-strip.word(paste0(unlist(existing.letters),collapse=""),word)
  tray.contents<-paste0(unlist(tray[tray$player==player,"tiles"]),collapse="")

  # pad out the surrounding cells to determine if the word is adjacent / overlaying
  c.x<-LETTERS[(min(match(unique(word.grid$c),LETTERS))-1):(max(match(unique(word.grid$c),LETTERS))+1)]
  r.x<-(min(as.integer(unique(word.grid$r)))-1):(max(as.integer(unique(word.grid$r)))+1)
  pad<-expand.grid(c=c.x,r=r.x)
  touch.x<-pad[!((pad$r==max(pad$r)|pad$r==min(pad$r))&(pad$c==pad$c[1]|pad$c==pad$c[nrow(pad)])),]

  # get the entire word if it's an add-on
  ifelse(d==1,
    {#find the whole row
    #start with the start point (that we know is in the word)
    #and go forward and backward
    full.row<-merge(board[board$r==r,],unique(rbind(words[words$r==r,],word.grid[word.grid$r==r,])),all.x=T)
    word.shift<-sum(cumprod(!is.na(full.row$lab)[c.ix:1]))-1 
    word.len<-sum(cumprod(!is.na(full.row$lab)[c.ix:15]))
    word.entire<-paste0(full.row$lab[(c.ix-word.shift):(c.ix+word.len-1)],collapse="")},
    {#find the whole column
    #start with the start point (that we know is in the word)
    #and go forward and backward
    full.row<-merge(board[board$c==c,],unique(rbind(words[words$c==c,],word.grid[word.grid$c==c,])),all.x=T)
    word.shift<-sum(cumprod(!is.na(full.row$lab)[r:1]))-1 
    word.len<-sum(cumprod(!is.na(full.row$lab)[r:15]))
    word.entire<-paste0(full.row$lab[(r+word.len-1):(r-word.shift)],collapse="")} # backwards because top >> bottom
  )

  # error handling
  if(is.na(sum(match(unlist(word.grid[,1:2]),valids)))) stop("ERROR, WORD OFF BOARD") # test for on board
  if(is.na(scrabble.dictionary[grep(paste0("^",gsub("0",".{1,1}",word.entire),"$"),scrabble.dictionary[,words])][1])) stop("ERROR, NOT IN DICTIONARY") # test spelling
  if(strip.word(word,paste0(existing.letters,tray.contents,collapse=""),T)==F) stop(paste0("MISSING LETTERS IN YOUR TRAY",player)) # check tray
  if(nrow(merge(touch.x,words))==0 & nrow(words)>0) stop("ERROR, YOU MUST TOUCH AN EXISTING LETTER") # position  


  score.base<-sum(sapply(char.vec(gsub(" ","0",word.entire)),function(x)rules[rules$letter==x,"score"]))
  ifelse(nrow(words)>0,
         word.specials<-merge(merge(words,word.grid,by=c("c","r"),all.y=T),board.filled),
         word.specials<-data.frame(c="H",r=8,lab.x=NA,lab.y=NA,t.w=1,d.w=2,stringsAsFactors=F))  
  #update the filled board
  words<<-unique(rbind(words,word.grid)) # clean up excess entries with unique
  new.tray<<-paste0(tray[tray$player==player&!is.na(tray$tiles),"tiles"],collapse="")

  lapply(1:nchar(word),function(x)new.tray<<-sub(substr(word,x,x),"",new.tray))
  tray[tray$player==player,]<<-data.frame(player=player,tiles=unlist(c(lapply(1:nchar(new.tray),function(x)substr(new.tray,x,x)),draw.tiles(n=7-nchar(new.tray)))),stringsAsFactors=F)

  #update the scorecard
  score.upd<<-score.base*prod(as.matrix(word.specials[is.na(word.specials$lab.x),c("t.w","d.w")]))
  scorecard<<-rbind(scorecard,data.frame(player=player,word=word.entire,score=score.upd))

  # toggle players and draw the board
  switch.player()  
  draw.game()
}

##############################
#                            #
# PLAY SCRABBLE!             #
#                            #
# PRE-RUN WITH SEED VALUE    #
# FOR CONSISTENT RESULTS     #
#                            #
##############################


  init.game(6) #LEAVE SEED PARAM BLANK FOR RANDOM GAME
  draw.game()
  tray[tray$player==1,"tiles"]<-draw.tiles(7)
  tray[tray$player==2,"tiles"]<-draw.tiles(7)
  draw.game()

  add.word("WIVES",c="H",8,1)
  add.word("SLANT",c="L",8,2)
  add.word("ONCE",c="K",5,1)
  add.word("BONE",c="K",11,2)
  add.word("BEET",c="K",11,1)
  add.word("GREET",c="M",14,2)
  add.word("EROS",c="L",13,1)
  add.word("BOSS",c="O",15,2)
  add.word("WAVY",c="H",8,2)
  add.word("MOVE",c="F",6,1)
  add.word("MIN ",c="F",6,2)
  add.word("FIZ ",c="C",3,1)
  add.word("WILD",c="D",4,2)
  add.word("PATE",c="N",8,2)
  add.word("J IL",c="A",2,1)
  add.word("PINE",c="I",9,2)
  add.word("SUPINE",c="I",11,2)
  add.word("HUGS",c="F",11,1)
  add.word("DEATH",c="F",15,2)
  add.word("RACK",c="E",13,1)
  add.word("DUAL",c="F",15,1)
  add.word("REMOVE",c="D",6,1)
  add.word("ROOFER",c="D",11,2)
  add.word("DOXY",c="C",9,1)
  add.word("HAIR",c="A",11,1)
  add.word("HEARD",c="A",11,2)
  add.word("QAT",c="B",12,2)
  add.word("ANNUL",c="H",7,1)
  add.word("WIN",c="D",4,1)
```