# Plot and fill chessboard-like area (and the similars) in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need some suggestion of how to plot 2D figures and fill them effectively in `R`. I need to visualize some mathematical "oddities", for example the Sierpiński gasket or a simple chessboard - and receive the effect similar to the following:

[image]

or

[image]

I thought about using the complex numbers to define the points but still have no clear idea how to fill particular areas (e.g. in two different colours).

Comment: [take a look at page 96](http://learnr.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/latbook.pdf)

Comment: If you can `plot` something,  you can `polygon` it to fill w/colors

Comment: take a look at the scrabble board here (answer 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280738/setting-up-a-scrabble-game-in-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like so?  Start with a matrix representing your data

```
mx <- matrix(rep(c(T, F), 5), nrow=3, ncol=3)
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and then melt/plot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(mx), aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, BrodieG! It will not be that simple in my problems (see my updated post), but it gives me a hint to simply *group* the points so as to  use ggplot2 to line and fill them based on this grouping.

Comment: @Marciszka, yes, so long as you have coordinates for each point and can mark a point as being in a state you should be able to do this.  Also, if you have large data sets, you may want to use [`geom_raster()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_raster.html)

Answer (score 4):

`geom_raster()` will be the fastest for square tiles of equal shape.

probably you want `geom_polygon()` - here is Sierpinski:

remember to use `coord_fixed(ratio=1)` or the shape proportions will scale to the shape of your viewer:

**EDIT - sorry realised looking at it I hadn't give you Sierpinski (not sure what I was thinking) fixed**

[image]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
t.h<-sin(2*pi/6)   # eq triangle unit height

sierpinski<-function(iter=3){
  n<-2^iter
  points<-ldply((n-1):0,function(x){
    data.frame(
      y=rep(n-x-1,x)*t.h/n,
      x=seq((from=(0.5/n)+(n-x)*(0.5/n)),by=1/n,length.out=x)
    )  
  })

  points$id<-1:nrow(points)

  rbind(
    points,
    points+matrix(c((t.h/n),(-0.5/n),0),nrow(points),ncol=3,byrow=T),
    points+matrix(c((t.h/n),(0.5/n),0),nrow(points),3,byrow=T)
  )
}

axiom<-data.frame(x=c(0,0.5,1),y=c(0,t.h,0))

iterations<-6

ggplot() + theme_bw() + coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  geom_polygon(data=axiom,aes(x,y), fill="orange") + 
  lapply(1:iterations,function(x){
    geom_polygon(data=sierpinski(x),aes(x,y,group=id), fill="white")
  })
```

Also, something you should be aware of with these very precise recursive & series models. Sometimes ggplot will not provide an image looking precisely as you expect. e.g. see below for a cantor dust diagram:

With ggplot (using raster) you can see that even with a high-res output, the 'legs' don't look consistent, whereas you know mathematically that they are. If you download the image and zoom, you'll see the inconsistencies at the bottom.

[image]

In the code below, I have shown how you can generate your own precise image by creating a raw png file on the fly. Don't be afraid of doing this if you need precision! The output of the raw image generation is below:

Good luck!

[image]

```
# CANTOR

# NUMBER OF ROWS
n<-9

# MATRIX
m<-matrix(sapply(n:1,function(x){
    str.zero<-rep(0,3^(x-1))
    str.one<-rep(1,3^(x-1))
    rep(c(str.one,str.zero),length.out=3^(n-1))
}),nrow=n,byrow=T)

# CLEANUP
m.cantor<-apply(m,2,cumprod)    

# ggplot

ggplot(melt(m.cantor)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_raster(aes(x=Var2,y=-Var1,alpha=value),color="white")

# MAKE IMAGE FROM RAW DATA
# LIBRARIES REQUIRED
require(png)

# AT THE MOMENT WE HAVE A SHORT, WIDE MATRIX
dim(m.cantor)
# [1]    9 6561
# so let's scale it up say * 700 to make an approx square image (9 x 700 = 6300 ~ 6561)
# basically we're running through each row and replicating x 700
# then putting the pixels in a matrix with the new height (n=9 * 700) 
new.m<-matrix(sapply(1:n,function(x)rep(m.cantor[x,],700)),nrow=n*700,byrow=T)

dim(new.m) # check the size
#[1] 6300 6561       *  OK!

# then let's put it in raw image format
# png expects an array of 4 matrices, R,G,B and alpha

img.raw<-array(c((1-new.m), # R,G,B pixels oinverted so 1=shading
                 (1-new.m),   # no G
                 (1-new.m),   # no B
                 new.m^0    #note I'm putting this to ^0 to make all alphas 1
                 ),
               dim=c(dim(new.m),4))


writePNG(img.raw,"cantor.png")
```