# Create Boolean DF based on whether an observation appears under each variable from an intial DF

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

I want to have 0/1 based on whether an observation appears for a variable. [For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667964/how-to-make-a-graph-of-clustered-boolean-variables-in-r). The scenario is that I have multiple datasets and I want to show which datasets share the same variable. I already have one dataframe with everything needed, like so:

```
ds1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'I')
ds2 <- c('A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J')
ds3 <- c('B', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
df <- data.frame(ds1, ds2, ds3)
```

I want to produce a graph similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667981/14416999) but my data is set up differently. So my first step is to create a Boolean df similar to how it is in that question. My thought process was to rearrange the df into two columns first, with dataset names and variable names (df2). Then compare it against all unique variable names (udf) to have TRUE/FALSE based on whether it appears or not.

```
df2 <- gather(df, ds_name, var_name, 1:3)
udf <- unique(df2$var_name)
```

But I am having trouble with that next step. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R` to create the table and then use `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(names(df)[col(df)], unlist(df))),
       aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = factor(Freq))) + 
       geom_tile(color='black')
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option with `tabyl` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
     tabyl(name, value) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'name1') %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = name, y = name1, fill = factor(value))) + 
           geom_tile(color = 'black')
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the mentioned solution you can try this. Reshape the data in long and wide format to obtain the binary values. Then reshape again to long and plot. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions. It is close to what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(var=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from=var) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0) %>%
  rename(data=name) %>%
  pivot_longer(-data) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=data, y=name, fill=factor(value))) + geom_tile(color='black')+
  scale_fill_manual('Value',values = c('tomato','cyan3'))
```

Output:

[image]